# 32 bit-processor download

Tags: downloads

What download if any should I use on an old Dell dimension B110? I believe it is a 32 bit machine. The old XP software is corrupted and I would like to try a desktop version of Ubuntu or something similar just for online brousing and video streaming. I would be a new/first time user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar) Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Pay attention to the amount of RAM. You'll need at least 512MB of RAM.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  I don't know your cpu/machine , but from what I see in thomasrutter's answer, I would suggest a lighter flavor of Ubuntu, such as Lubuntu or Xubuntu.  They contain the same Ubuntu based, but Lubuntu contains the LXDE interface (assuming you use Lubuntu 18.04 LTS or the long-term-support release, and not Lubuntu 18.10) or XFCE (Xubuntu 18.04 LTS).  I'm suggesting LTS or long-term-support releases as they have three (3) years of support, longer than the 9 months of for example Lubuntu/Xubuntu 18.10.  Ubuntu releases are *yy.mm* in format, so 18.04 = 2018.April release

Comment: As for which is best for you, your own tastes will have a huge influence on that. LXDE approaches the GUI (graphical user interface) one way, XFCE slightly different. It's this 'gui' or desktop that makes it different to the much heavier GNOME default in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.  GNOME uses more memory, more cpu cycles so will appear slower than LXDE or XFCE.  Even if you have a fast modern machine, some people still prefer the lighter DEsktops just because they love the speed of them. Your machine's memory may also influence the best for you, but download, write to ISO & try for yourself.

Comment: B110 came with 512MB RAM as standard. Should be fine for desktop Ubuntu, though obviously more is better.  Maybe it's already been upgraded.

Answer (score 2):

Your computer has an [Intel Celeron D 325](https://ark.intel.com/products/27108/Intel-Celeron-D-Processor-325-256K-Cache-2-53-GHz-533-MHz-FSB-) processor which indeed only has a 32-bit instruction set.  You can download a 32-bit installer image from the alternative downloads page under "Network installer".  It's called a Network installer to distinguish it from the Live installer, which boots to a live Ubuntu installation, and because it loads its packages from the internet as it installs so it requires a network connection.  The Live installer is no longer available for 32-bit Ubuntu.

https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads

You'll want the "i386" architecture, and then download the .iso file, which is around 50 MB.

Note: the .iso files are intended to be burned as images to a CD, but if you don't have a CD drive you can write it as a raw image to a USB stick and it should work as long as you can boot from USB devices, as it is a hybrid image.  How you do this depends on your OS.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, that was a pretty low end system.  I have my doubts as to how well any flavor of Ubuntu may run on it.  If you find it to be a poor experience, you may do better with something like [Q4OS](https://www.q4os.org/), which is really aimed at bringing modern software advancements to such low-end systems.

I'm impressed you've been able to keep it running this long.